# Definition of uniformly convergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I have come-across the following situation in my reading about double sequences $\{s_{m,n}\}_{m,n \in \mathbb{N}}$.

In my situation, it is supposed $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} s_{m,n}$ exists as a definite number, for all values of $m$ (note: this is not a hypothesis which necessarily implies the following statement, it is just something which is given and may or may not be important for this question). What is meant by the statement: "the sequences 
\begin{eqnarray} \{s_{m,1}\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \ , \ \{s_{m,2}\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \ , \ldots  \ , \ \{s_{m,n}\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \ , \ \ldots \quad \quad \quad \quad (1)\end{eqnarray}
are uniformly convergent with respect to $m$"?

I know of the definition of uniform convergence for sequences **of functions** $\{f_{m}(x)\}_{m\in \mathbb{N}}$ over some interval $(a,b)$. But the context of (1) is that $s_{m,n}$ are just sequences of numbers, not functions, i.e. there's no variable "$x$".

Thank you for answers and comments

Comment: For each $m$ and for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists ... OR ... For any $\epsilon>0$ there exists ...  and this is true for each $m$.  The latter is "uniform."

Comment: @B.S.Thomson so whether there exists some $M_{\epsilon}$ which works universally for all values of $m$, this is uniform convergence of a sequence of numbers?

Comment: additional: no sorry, this can't be right, or I don't understand.

Comment: You got it.  You were just expecting something more familiar looking.  In fact $s_{mn}$ is a sequence of functions if you think of it correctly.